# Moving slow database calls from MVC to background application - advice please

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, architecture

I have an MVC web site, where users can search for large recordsets from SQL Server and Oracle databases. Some of these recordsets can be very large, with many thousands of records. Sadly, it is a user requirement that they do not make their searches more specific.

When a user posts their search request to the database, my web page is hanging before often timing out (due to the amount of time taken to query the database).

We are thinking about removing the expensive database calls from the MVC site, and sending the query to a separate process to run in the background. When the query is complete, we can notify the user.

My proposed solution is:

1) When the user completes the search form in the web page, to simply display a message that the results are being generated and will be sent when complete
2) Send the SQL query to a database which can contain a list of SQL queries that need to be processed
3) Create a Windows Service which checks this database every couple of minutes for new queries
4) This Windows Service then queries the database. When the query is completed, it will create a CSV of the results, and email this to the user

I am looking for some advice and comments on my above approach? What do folks think of this as an approach to process expensive database calls in the background?

Generally speaking the requests will be made infrequently, but as mentioned, will be for a great amount of data. There is a chance that two or more requests could be made at the same time, but this will be infrequent.

I will also look at optimising the databases.

Grateful for any tips.

Martin :)

Comment: Is your application interactive (e.g. there is a web UI) or just batch? If interactive, you can utilize e.g. websockets, otherwise just provide a link for your users to check the results later.

Comment: Hi, it is a web based MVC application - the user builds up search criteria using form controls and this is converted into a Select statement by the MVC controller. They will want to press submit on the web page, and either get (fairly) quick results, or will prefer to get a message telling them that results will be available later, and then close the browser and do something else...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to supplement the existing code to execute the query on a separate thread so that periodic keep-alive updates can be sent to the requesting page while you wait for the query results. Similar to the way the insurance quote agregator pages work.
  A second option is to make the results available as a hyperlink when they are ready and then communicate that either through the website or by email to the user.
  Option three if these queries are not completely ad-hoc type queries then you could profile for the most frequent combinations and pre-compute them periodically placing the results into new tables (sort of halfway to optimising the current database structure).
  The caveat there is that the data won't be as up to date - but given the time the queries are currently taking it probably isn't that important to be up to the second?

Whichever solution you choose I think it's going to depend on the user expectation - Do they know what they want and just send one big query and get it and be happy? or do they try several queries to find the right combination of parameters? If the latter then waiting for an email delivery of results might not be acceptable to them.  But if what they want is a downloadable results document and they know what they want first time then it may.  The only problem I see here is emails going astray or taking longer than the user thinks it should causing the request to be resubmitted multiple times and increasing the server workload - caching queries and results is probably a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think the database queries could take minutes in some cases, so really can't expect them to wait for the results in real time. But I would be interested in ideas where the MVC app could fire the queries aysnc, and then send the results by email etc. It just felt to me that it wasn't the right job of a web application, and I should look at background process. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to introduce layer of abstraction like messaging broker. Request will go in queue and batch layer will consume request from queue and once heavy work is done, batch layer will notify web layer again via messaging broker, Request-Reply pattern.
In addition on database side it is allways good to optimize queries.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. There could be a long delay while the batch layer is working....the user will have closed their browser by then, so the web layer will no longer exist.